# MariaDB Backup on Swisscom Cloud

Tags: swisscomdev

I'm interested in the MariaDB Service from the Swisscom Cloud.
https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/mariadb.html

What backup capabilities are offered by the Swisscom Cloud?
Is there something similar like on pivotal cloud foundry?
https://docs.pivotal.io/p-mysql/backup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perfect timing for asking: we have just released major update to our platform and instant back/restore for MariaDB is a new feature that is available from today!

You can take backups and restore them from the administration console (GUI)

Michal Maczka
Product Manager Application Cloud

Comment: Thanks Michael for the feedback. Just checked https://console.developer.swisscom.com and saw to new backup functionality for MariaDB

Comment: @michal-maczka, could you please get someone to look into this functionality as it doesn't seem to be working for me (I only get "error" as a result - no error message, though) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's a [MariaDB backup plugin](https://github.com/gsmachado/cf-mariadb-backup-plugin) for the [CF CLI](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/install-go-cli.html):
https://github.com/gsmachado/cf-mariadb-backup-plugin

Then, you are able to automate backup creations -- e.g., you can come up with a bash script to create a backup every day, or every two days.